# Google Cloud Function

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am following the google tutorial on creating a simple helloWorld function and deploying it on google cloud. My machine is Windows 7 - 64 bit.
    I am following this link: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/tutorials/http

```
However I am facing few issues here:
1. Before You Begin -> Enable the API: getting the following error: "You have no permissions to use requested API"

2. Install the Cloud SDK: When I run the downloaded installer, following error comes: "Unzip failed: Error opening ZIP file"
I however installed SDK from another link:
https://cloud.google.com/sdk/downloads#versioned

3. Unable to install alpha component. Used this command:
gcloud components install alpha

4. Deploying the function: 
ERROR: (gcloud.alpha.functions.deploy) ResponseError: status=[403], code=[Forbid
den], message=[Cannot access Google Cloud Functions API in project gcf-project-1
]

If anybody knows the solution, please help.

Thanks,
Robin
```

Answer (score 8):

it might be silly but be sure to enable the cloud functions api in your project settings on the gcloud dashboard website.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Google Cloud Functions was just released as public beta.  The commands are slightly different (e.g. you don't install alpha components)! It should all work now without whitelisting.

https://cloud.google.com/functions/

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud Functions is currently in Alpha, which means it's whitelist only.  You're getting this error because your account is not whitelisted.  You'll need to sign up for access to the Alpha, which you can do [here](http://cloud.google.com/functions)

Comment: Does it take a while to get access to Alpha upon signing up to be whitelisted, or should that happen immediately?